# Border issues on HTML Table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a table where I don't want any internal border, except the one that separate header from lines.

In my css, I have:

```
table { ...
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-style: solid;
}
table th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 2pt solid #830504;
  padding: 4px  8px ;
  text-align: center;
}
table tr {
  padding:4px;
}

table td {
  border-collapse: none;
  padding:4px;
}
```

And I get the following

[image]

How can I get rid off those 2 spaces at the right and left of the th bottom border?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full code? With the HTML (or create a JSFiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably comes from the fact you are using `border-collapse` on `td` and `th` but not the `table`.

Here's the difference :

```css
.collapse {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Bob</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Bob</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this as a minimum basic table css

```
.tbl {
  width: 100%; /* you may change the width in % */
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.tbl * {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
thead, tbody, tr {
  width: inherit;
}
th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  hyphens: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
@media (max-width: 767.9px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
}
```

With this html

```
<div class="tbl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

With this css, your table is responsive for all screen sizes and you only have to give some colors and/or borders to the `th` and `td`

Answer (score -1):

Reset the `border-spacing` which has a default of c.2px.

If you set this to `0`, the issue is resolved.

```css
table {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ddd;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* this */
}

table th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 10pt solid #830504;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr {
  padding: 8px;
}

table td {
  padding: 4px;
  border-collapse: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

using the CSS you provided just add `border-spacing: 0;`
 to your table style

```
table {
            border-width: 2px;
            border-color: #ddd;
            border-style: solid;
            border-spacing: 0;

        }
```

You can view it working here
https://jsfiddle.net/hd60zset/3/

Comment: @Aripheus The example should, ideally, be in a Stack Snippet, not on an external link.

Comment: As this answer solves the OP case, I would like to point out that it may cause _surprises_ and doubled borders between `td`/`tr` and `table` borders in generic cases because the `border-collapse: collapse` property is not set on the `table` element.